# How to programmatically edit layer names on existing maps created on maps.google.com?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have 67 maps that were manually created on maps.google.com by importing different KML shape files for each layer. Each map has 10 layers. [Here is one of the maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?mid=1O8_f5cGBUNVGH0ofdBPipRe1IgIsexIj&ll=41.01315990526099%2C-76.07276947753901&z=9).

I need to edit a few of the layer names in all 67 maps. The layer names that I want to edit are all the same across all 67 files (example: "2021 Proposed PA House" -> "2021 FDPA Proposed PA House").

The Google map files are stored on my Google Drive. I tried to use a Google App Script to modify the files, but it didn't work: I think the files are binary (KMZ) vs. text (KML). Here is the function, it returns an

> "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getBlob on object DriveApp.File."

```
function update_label() {
  var fileId = "1r7c0jqUc3JiPdVLjjctsuCkOevO042ob"; 
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var blob = file.getBlob();
  var str = blob.getDataAsString();
  var r = str.replace('<name>2021 Proposed PA House</name>', '<name>2021 FDPA Proposed PA House</name>');
  file.setContent(r);
}
```

Is there anyway to edit these files on Google Drive?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have updated the original question.

Comment: Is the error consistent? Create a [new project](https://script.new) and test it there again.

Comment: Yes. If I change the fileId to point to a text file, the code works fine. When I change it back to point to the Google Map, I get the same error.

Comment: When I tested your script using a KML file from your sample map, no error occurs. I apologize for this. So, in order to correctly confirm your issue, can you provide the sample file for replicating your issue?

Comment: Yes, the script works on a KML file, but not on a Google Map file.  

Try this: In the original post, open the map. Make a copy of it (click on the 3-dot menu next to the map's name, select "copy map").  Google will make a copy of the map in the root folder of your Google Drive. Try to use the script on that file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, the file is `application/vnd.google-apps.map`. Unfortunately, this file cannot directly retrieve the Blob. It seems that this is the current specification. I apologize for this. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like DriveApp has any methods to work with this type of file. Are there other services that can?